# Removing zeros from column

Tags: excel

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

***Copy that which is of value 1 in column B from column A to coulmn C...***

I've managed to do this, but I would like to automatically remove the zeros and clump them up nicely together at the top.

[image]

Updated: [image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FILTER` instead:

```
=FILTER(A1:A6,B1:B6=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but it's not working for me. Check the updated post

Comment: What is your Excel version? FILTER is available for Excel 2019 and above

Comment: @TobiasBowley What excactly do you mean by "not working"? There are things about your last screenshot that don't make sense to me.

Comment: I got it working. I had to use a semicolon instead of a comma between A6 and B1. 

Thanks.